# Data changed completely by read.xlsx?

Tags: r, excel

I tried to read an Excel sheet that looks like this:
[image: screenshot1]

using the code,

```
listOne <- read.xlsx("RPG1_4-26.xlsx", sheet = 1, colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = TRUE)
```

and nothing else. I got a sheet in R looking like this:
[image: screenshot2]

...??????? I tried turning each of the values false, but it didn't do anything. Help???

Comment: The data you show from reading the file in R does not include columns that are present in the picture of your Excel sheet. The columns Status, IPAddress, and Finished are all missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a partial answer because it suggests the cause but not the solution.

Those numbers look like Excel's internal representation of dates.

To confirm that, select cell A3 (11/19/20 10:57) in Excel and change its type from Custom to General. Notice that it now displays as 44148.48, the same value that appears in your R document.

It looks like read.xlsx doesn't recognise these as dates so is copying the raw data unchanged.

Incidentally, why does the Excel document duplicate the headers?

Perhaps read.xlsx deduces the data types from the second row. That row is probably formatted as General. If it assumes that subsequent rows are also General that could explain why the dates are misinterpreted.

Comment: You were completely right about the Custom formatting; I copied the data and pasted values only, that seemed to get me the values I wanted! Thank you!